# How can I test the file type (ascii, binary, etc) of git objects?

Tags: git

I want to find all the files in a given git branch that are ascii/text, from a **bare** git repository, and add up their total size.

Since this is a bare repo, it has no working tree and the solution of simply checking out the branch and testing the files directly will not work. There may be hundreds of these repositories totalling hundreds of GB and they are read-only for the purposes of this task. This means that creating a working tree is not an option, and the size of repositories means making a copy of each one and creating a working tree in the copy is impractical.

I can list all the objects belonging to a particular branch in a bare git repository like so:

```
git ls-tree -r master --long
```

This gives me the object hash:

```
100644 blob 486a23256c437b811b5647e40517a35964f60dc6      42    file1.txt
100644 blob f7b528c3a1412c12213e56394b679397bd4ecaa7     131    file2.xml
100644 blob 773c90bbb7ab5552d47ce2fb153fc9d18ed0d386    5617    file3.jpg
100644 blob 420cb792e80a97c89db9c9d7339b4fb9a680aa43   13130    file3.zip
```

In the above example I want to get only the first two plaintext objects but I don't know how to test an object itself for a file type.

Comment: If the repo is non-bare, this is `git ls-files --eol`.

Comment: @JoshLee: if only this worked in bare repositories (which do have an index!) ... and: it sort of does! `git read-tree <commit>` and then `git ls-files --eol`. Note: if you're using the index to track a deployment (`git --work-tree=... checkout` in a post-receive hook, for instance) you might want to use a temporary index for this.

Comment: @torek if I understand correctly, `git read-tree <commit>` creates a temporary / cached index? I'm trying to work out where this is stored or written to. It seems you can clear it with `git read-tree --empty`, I'm just curious where that info is being stored in the first place

Comment: @daveruinseverything: "the" index is `.git/index`, or, in a bare repo, just `index`. You can set up an alternate file with the environment variable `GIT_INDEX_FILE`. If you use `git worktree add` to create extra work-trees, they each get their own `HEAD` and `index` (and other files) in directories within `.git/worktrees/`. The one in `.git/index` is just the distinguished, main, default index for the main repository and its worktree-if-any.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Git itself does not distinguish between text and binary files. Many of the front-end porcelain tools do, but internally there isn’t a difference. The best way to figure out which is which is to use a non-git-based tool, `file`. To get the contents to send in to `file`, you can use `git show`. For example, if you ran `git show 486a23256c437b811b5647e40517a35964f60dc6 | file -`, you might get `/dev/stdin: ASCII text`. If you ran `git show f7b528c3a1412c12213e56394b679397bd4ecaa7 | file -`, you might get `/dev/stdin: XML 1.0 document text`.

In general, `file` tries to make anything that looks like plain text have the word `text` somewhere in the output, and nothing that does not look like text. More specifically, the `man` page for `file` says:

> The type printed will usually contain one of the words text (the file contains only printing characters and a few common control characters and is probably safe to read on an ASCII terminal), executable (the file contains the result of compiling a program in a form understandable to some UNIX kernel or another), or data meaning anything else (data is usually ‘binary’ or non-printable). Exceptions are well-known file formats (core files, tar archives) that are known to contain binary data.

So, if you pipe the output of `git show` through `file`, and then look for `text` in the output, you should be able to determine if it’s text or binary.

Comment: It's worth noting that what `file` thinks may not match Git's guess, and if you use `.gitattributes` to tell bits of Git porcelain whether some file names or glob patterns are specifically text or binary, this won't account for that either. It might be nice if Git had a plumbing command to inquire as to what Git is guessing about a file's type (a la `--path` and `--textconv` in `git cat-file -p`).

Comment: If there is such a thing I don’t know about it, but I hope there is.

Comment: See Josh Lee's comment and my reply: `git ls-files --stage` may be useful; with a bare repository you need to `git read-tree` the desired tree into the index (or into a temporary index if you want to avoid disturbing the main one).

Comment: @DanielH I tried piping `git show` to `file` but couldn't work out how `file` would read from stdin - all I needed was a dash! Thank you. I'll test this solution, and will compare it to the temporary tree @torek suggested as well

Comment: Yeah, adding the hyphen is a standard way to get programs to read from standard in; not everything recognizes it but most do.

Comment: Checking for the text "text" is not reliable to detect if something is non-binary. E.g. SVG files are plain text (XML) but `file` returns `SVG Scalable Vector Graphics image`.